# Array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Creating a small application to generate random numbers. See the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/dd976/).

Having an issue with the function that generates the numbers. There are 3 variables that control the output. The count of the numbers in a set/sequence, the number of the sets, and a number to limit the generated number, max number.

I created 2 loops to generate the numbers in sets. The inner loop creates a set of numbers (an array), and the outer loop adds that set to `setArr`, another array.

So I created 2 arrays. The one that will hold the current generated set `temp`, and the one that will hold the whole sets, `setsArr`.

Inner loop creates a set, and the outer loop pushes the created set to `setsArr`. And before executing again I empty the `temp` array. So this goes on and on.

But this doesn't work. I must be missing something. Any help?

```
function gen() {
    var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;
    var sets = document.getElementById("sets").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;

    var setsArr = [];
    var temp    = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            temp.push(num);
        }
        setsArr.push(temp);
        temp.length = 0;
    }

    console.log(setsArr);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? At a glance, it looks like temp should be declared in the outer loop, and not outside both loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're pushing the `temp` array to `setsArr`, it is not copied but referenced. Emptying it will empty the array in `setsArr`. Also when always pushing the same array, you will get `setsArr[0] == setsArr[1]`…

Instead, create a new array object on every iteration:

```
var setsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        temp.push(num);
    }
    setsArr.push(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/dd976/1/)***

Setting the length of the array to 0 was affecting every array placed into the parent array. Instead, use a local variable there, and it will create a new instance to use each time. This will properly allow for unique arrays.

```
var setsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    var temp = [];//local array instantiated
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        temp.push(num);
    }
    setsArr.push(temp);//save unique array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
temp.length = 0;
```

Setting the length of the array to 0 wipes out its contents. That's why your arrays are empty.

Comment: He said he *wanted* to "*empty the temp array*". Why shouldn't he?

Comment: What he wants is to set `temp` to be a new empty array (`temp = []`) not empty out the array he just `push`ed into `setsArr` which is what the code is currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/PtpTx/)

use local variable and then delete the local variable and do not wait for garbage collector.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        temp.push(num);
    }
    setsArr.push(temp);
    delete temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var generate    = document.getElementById("generate");
generate.onclick = gen;

function gen() {
var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;

var sets = document.getElementById("sets").value;
var max = document.getElementById("max").value;

var setsArr = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    setsArr[i] = new Array(); 
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        setsArr[i][j]=num;
    }
}
console.log(setsArr);
}
```

Now its working fine i updated your fiddle